# ExactTarget AmpScript SMS - Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

I am using below AMPscript in sms to display current time in SMS.

But I am getting blank message where I have used the function.

```
%%=SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())=%%
```

Can you please help above is not working for SMS but same is working fine for email template

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 functions worked for me (Outbound SMS):

```
%%=SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())=%% and %%=v(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()))=%%
```

If you know the specific timezone conversion, you could use the [DateAdd](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/dateadd/) function to manually alter the datetime.

Comment: @Praneet, Cameron's 2 functions worked for me too. Are you sure that the inline AMPscript code is not within an AMPscript block? e.g. %%[ your code ]%%

Comment: Good thinking @EliotHarper. Praneet, double check your AMPScript Blocks, and possibly try the verbose method, documented here: [SystemDateToLocalDate](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/systemdatetolocaldate/)